# Create a dummy value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm creating a data warehouse in SSIS and SQL Server. Now for handling the late arriving dimensions I want to create a dummy value with surrogate key -999.
Let's take my `Products` table for example where I have the `ProductID` already  and the `Product_pk` which is my surrogate key.

[Product table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzhjB.png)

The surrogate key is generated automatically. Is there a way to insert a dummy value with a specific surrogate key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the identity value by setting a parameter in your session, [`identity_insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
set identity_insert products off;

insert into products (productId, . . .)
    values (-1, . . . )

set identity_insert products on;
```

Note that only one table in a session can have `identity_insert` turned off.  So, you should turn it back on when you are done.